# iphone viewController

Tags: iphone

I am creating an application in which I have to pass data from 16 `UITextFields`, store them in an array in form of a class object and display all the objects from that array in other `viewController`.

How can you pass data from one `viewController` to the another?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two view controllers named `viewController1` and `viewController2`. Have an instance variable `textData` of `NSArray` in `viewcontroller2`. Make sure you add `@property` and `@synthesize` to the variable. Allocate the array in the `init` method of `viewController2` and you can pass the array from the first viewController to the second by

```
viewController2.textData = viewController1.textArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually communication between unrelated view controllers is a symptom of ugly design. I'd avoid that.

A singleton object might be your best choice. **Never ever** use the application's delegate or `NSUserDefaults` to share data between objects. The same applies for saving data in a plist on disk and reload it from the other controller. That's just extremely bad design.

By the way: whatever is your skill level, get this book, [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022).
It's not directly related to iPhone development, but it explains Cocoa's design and patterns in a clear way. Understanding it will help you a lot in designing your future applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare array in the second view controller and set the property and synthesize it and  then you can pass data to second view controller from the first by

```
secondviewcontroller *obj = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]init];
obj.array = data;
```

Comment: thats the traditional C++ way. I want in Obj-c way using id<protocol>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in an easy way. In the first controller (e.g. `FirstViewController`) you can store all the fields in an array:

```
NSArray *_fields;
```

Then, you make the array accessible through the `@property` construct:

```
@property (readonly) NSArray *fields;
```

And in the .m implementation you make them available through the `@synthesize` call:

```
@synthesize fields = _fields;
```

In the second controller (e.g. `SecondViewController`) you should have a pointer to the first one, using the same above constructs:

```
FirstViewController *_controller;
```

then

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController *controller;
```

and in the .m you will have:

```
@synthesize controller = _controller;
```

When you create the second controller, you will have to save the pointer to the first one. E.g.

```
FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
second.controller = first;
```

Then you will be able to use `second.controller.fields` to read the UITextField instances in the first controller.

Comment: About what? Ask and I'll answer ... I corrected a couple of thing to make it clearer.

Comment: where to define FirstViewController and SecondViewController ? in MainWindow.xib ?

Comment: You should define them as classes that extend the `UIViewController` class, and if you want you can instantiate them using a new .nib file created through Interface Builder.

Comment: i tried that .....My application has 16 UITextFields and i have separated them into 2 viewController each.I think i am messed  up with my code

Comment: Where did you put those 16 UITextFields? Did you define them programmatically or through IB? In the latter case, which controller are you modifying?

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of ways to achieve this. It all depends on what you need to do with the data and for how long you need to store it etc.

- You could have a singleton class which holds the data - singletons are accessible from anywhere in your application.
- You could store the data in the application delegate. It is also accessible from anywhere in your application: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
- Your viewControllers could talk to each other directly.
- <strike>You could store the data as user defaults ([NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i))</strike>
- You could store the data in a file (perhaps a plist?)

Comment: "You could store the data as user defaults (NSUserDefaults)" Don't do that. NSUserDefaults are meant to store user preferences, not any data.

Comment: using sigleton class ? is it possible ?.i  am new to this technology.I have switched from Java.

Comment: Here's the macros I use to create singletons: https://github.com/cjhanson/Objective-C-Optimized-Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Passing to much information from one view controller to the next is a clear tell sign of a bad Model-View-Controller design. Your application logic should be pushed down into the domain layer as much as possible.

I am guessing you are implementing some kind of *wizard* functionality. Introduce a new `FooWizardState` domain object, and pass that along from one view controller to the next. This way you can easily break down your first view controller from 16 text fields to say two controllers with 8 text fields each later if you need to, or the customer demands.

With this design you can also easily change of of the view controllers completely in case one step of the wizard needs to be redone for iPad/iPhone user interface idioms.